# Error installing Ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Whilst installing Ruby gems I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT:
 Failed to open TCP connection to api.rubygems.org:443 (A connection attempt fai
led because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time,
 or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
- connect(2) for "api.rubygems.org" port 443) (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.
8.gz)
```

Gems I've attempted to install:

- `Nokogiri`
- `Mechanize`
- `Bundler` (Obviously)

All producing the same error, I'm guessing it's all the gems, not just bundler.

I've never seen this before so I'm not sure what to do, could someone tell me what's going on? It's probably worth mentioning that I am on a secure network.

---

**UPDATE**:

I've attempted to initialize a new rule in my firewall that will allow me to use TCP connection through port 443 (the port that `gem install` runs off of); However I'm still getting the error

---

**UPDATE**:

I've done some research and attempted to update using `gem update --system` via [this](http://help.rubygems.org/discussions/problems/17672-gems-not-installing-due-to-timeout) resource. However it's still throwing the same error, and will not allow me to update

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: What happens when you try to go to https://rubygems.org/ in your browser?

Comment: @Uzbekjon I can't say. But yes it's something like that. I'm unable to install anything I'm going to attempt to allow it through the port and see what happens.

Comment: @user12341234 It opens, no lag, no nothing. It's not my connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what happened. However I was able to get onto another network and download gems.

There was no proxy, there was no VPN setup, but there was a default script so I'm guessing that had something to do with it.

So the resolution was I got onto a different network and successfully installed what I needed

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem recently and it was a proxy issue.

If you are on corporate network (work, university, dorm, etc.) probably you are too. Identify your proxy server information (see network settings) and try to add proxy info to your `gem install` command.

Depending on your gem version, one of these should work:

```
gem install --http-proxy http://[user]:[password]@[server]:[port]
gem install -p http://[user]:[password]@[server]:[port]
```

If that's your main net access, then you can set it to be used by default.     Create `.gemrc` file in your home dir (user folder in windows or linux) and set the proxy settings there:

```
http_proxy: http://[user]:[password]@[server]:[port]
```

Comment: This would probably work and all, except I'm not the network admin, so I don't have access to the proxy information

Comment: Try to check the proxy settings in your browser. if it is not set to automatic, just copy paste the values to your .gemrc file.

Comment: You do actually. What OS are you on? Google, how to see network and proxy settings. You are probably on DHCP network. Basically, when you physically connect to the server, your network settings are "sent/set" from the "central" server.

Comment: Well I've discovered that it's a type of script. Not a proxy, it's what they use for secure internet

Comment: I do have an idea, if I can connect to my phone wifi, I might be able to pull this off as a work around.

Comment: gem install --http-proxy http://[user]:[password]@[server]:[port] <ModuleName> worked for me

Answer (score -1):

Try to install them in non -proxy environment, It worked for me.